# Oracle db link to Azure. Problem with procedure compilation

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database, oracle19c

I've installed driver dg4msql to create connection between Oracle database and Azure SQL.

After creating the db link, I'm able to create simple views etc.

I have problem with procedure compilation (code works fine outside the procedure).

Error:

> Error ORA-02050: transaction 8.17.2281 rolled back, some remote DBs may be in-doubt
> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
> ORA-02063: preceding line from AZURE_DB_LINK

After that I need to reconnect session because even normal select which worked earlier returns error:

> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
> ORA-02063: preceding line from AZURE_DB_LINK
> 28500. 00000 -  "connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:"
> *Cause:    The cause is explained in the forwarded message.
> *Action:   See the non-Oracle system's documentation of the forwarded message.
> Error at Line: 9 Column: 25

My `/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dg4msql/admin/initAZURE.ora` looks like this:

```
# This is a customized agent init file that contains the HS parameters
# that are needed for the Database Gateway for Microsoft SQL Server

#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=address:1433//test
# alternate connect format is hostname/serverinstance/databasename
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=OFF
#HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT=user
#HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD=password
#HS_FDS_TRANSACTION_LOG=HS_TRANSACTION_LOG
HS_FDS_TRANSACTION_MODEL=READ_ONLY
HS_FDS_ENCRYPT_SESSION=SSL
HS_FDS_VALIDATE_SERVER_CERT=0
HS_OPEN_CURSORS=100
HS_FDS_RESULTSET_SUPPORT=FALSE
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database supports server-side cursors but only for some cursor types and behaviors, that may be the reason behind the errors you received based on the agent ini file you shared with us.

The same error you will get with Azure Data Warehouse were server-side cursors are not supported. On Azure Data Warehouse you get the same ORA-28500 and ORA-02063 errors but you get a NativeErr 46706 error also.

On the Oracle documentation states that DG4ODBC requires cursor support to be able to execute queries, but it doesn't necesarily have to be server-side.

Some TDS drivers have an option that you can try setting in the drivers config (not in the gateway config).

```
useCursors=false
```

You may also need to set:

```
selectMethod=direct
```

Comment: The problem is that dg4msql doesn't have drivers config (only gateway config).

Comment: That is the solution/workaround provided by Oracle support.

Comment: But i'm using dg4msql not DG4ODBC.

Comment: The cause is the same, but the workaround is available only on DG4ODBC. Search the error on Metalink (Oracle Support)

Comment: I tried ODBC. I set SelectMethod=direct and useCursors=false. But right now even simple select doesn't work - ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cursor support is not an implemented feature for SQL Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint. {42000,NativeErr = 46706}

Comment: Are you sure you can access Azure SQL from that host? Please ping the server. You would get host unreachable but will get the IP of the Azure SQL logical server? Are you able to get that IP?

Comment: Yes, Im sure. By using dg4msql im able to run select but there is problem with procedure compilation so i changed driver to odbc. Here nothing works, even simple select.

Comment: Based on Metalink documentation it should have been the other way around. They do not offer any workaround with dg4msql

Comment: Do You any have idea what can be missing in driver settings or gateway settings?

Comment: I know for sure both, dg4msql and DG4ODBC, use by default cursors and Azure SQL Database has a limited support for them. What more settings are available for avoiding the use of cursors on DB Links, I don't know.